# WinAppDriver or FlaUI can`t run exe normally

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, appium, desktop-application, winappdriver

I made a simple code to run my *.exe
manually it stats ok, but when i use winapp driver or FlaUI (i tried FlaUI2 and FlaUI3)

it gave me errors:
2 of this [the specified file was not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFJQ9.png)
1 this [acces violation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8OlO.png)
and after those it will start my program (i dont know in normal condition or broken)

I tried my code on notepad++.exe and everything works